# Slim POST method and AngularJs Http POST Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-post, slim

I was trying to figure out how to fix this issue - I'm not sure if it is related to my local config or on this library.

I use Angular.js to send request to REST server with Chatwork/slim-json-request as middleware. Here are the request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2019
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5q7WNrrXPm77DsQv
Host:test.localhost
Origin:http://localhost:9002
Referer:http://localhost:9002/Register
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
```

Now, in the function call, when I try to print out the values:

`$app->request->getMediaType()` returns 'multipart/form-data'

but when I do:

`$app->request->getBody()` returns empty, this should return key-value pair sent via form submit (POST)

and when I do:

`$app->request->post('param')` return the value passed by the request.

I am using Angular.js with Slim and Chatwork/slim-json-request from [here](https://github.com/chatwork/slim-json-request).

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try to do this without using the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

use firefox network in development tools and check your requests sometimes it just sends OPTIONS request in Cross origin(I insist on firefox because it's network tool is much more detailed than chrome and safari)
Check this out:
[CORS POST request to REST server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093169/angularjs-post-request-does-not-work-correctly-on-firefox)